# how to use window in GWT

Tags: gwt

My project is using GWT 2.7, I have code as below

```
Window.open(url, winName.replace(" ", "_"), "menubar=no,
location=false, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no, dependent=true");
```

I expect: open only in same window if open more one. 
It's running as my expected in chrome/firefox. But, in IE8 always open new window.

How to fixed it in IE for open in same window? please help me

Comment: Can you makw your expectations more readable? It is hard to find the gist in them.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265344/open-same-tab-in-ie8-9